# How many 5-permutations of Q are there? (No repetition of character within a string and order matters)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

**How many 5-permutations of Q are there? (No repetition of character within a
string and order matters)**

Q = {A, B, C, D, E}.

So I think i'm supposed to be using the formula $(^n_k) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k!)}$

I think I know what I'm doing but not sure. Is it correct to say $5!/(5-5)!(5!)$ which $ = 120/1*120 = 1$ ?

Comment: No, that is the formula if order doesn't matter as one is going to use all the characters so there is only one combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for permutaion with $5$ different elements, then the answer is $5! = 120$

Comment: Cool thanks, I think I was looking at them as if they were integers but I guess since order matters it is just the element $n!$ is that correct? so if Q = {A,B} then it would be $2! = 2$? Or should I treat the **permutations** as my $n!$ and however many it asks then apply that number?

Comment: Yeah, that is the correct answer, but look out, if you had Q = {A,A,B}, then all of the possibilities is $3!$ but you have to divide with the cases, where the two(same) $A$-s are permutating between each other, and you have $2!=2$ possibilities for that, so the answer is $\frac{3!}{2!} = 3$. Your formula, what you used above is usable for example in lotto. If you have 10 numbers and 3 is winner, how many different winners can be? The answer here is $\frac{10!}{3!*(10-3)!}$, because you are not interested of their order.

Comment: Wow^ Thanks so much for the explanation

Comment: No problem, it is an easy thing to understand, but quite useful in a lot of cases. :)

Comment: I think this site is explaining it quite well: http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html